# Adding newer Flex SDK to Flex Builder 3 - how?

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, flexbuilder

I have a Flex Builder 3.0.2. It was shipped with Flex SDK 2.0.1 and 3.2. I would like to add the new Flex SDK 3.5. I followed the documentation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=build_6.html#162812:
- extracted SDK 3.5
- added into my SDK list
- set to default
- restart Flex Builder
- clean project

But it's just not working. There are many functions from the documentation I can't use still (but should be available with SDK 3.5). How can I use SDK 3.5?

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check under project properties -> Flex Compiler, that you're not compiling against a specific SDK, instead of the default one you've set.

Also you might need to target Flash Player 10, in which case you might want to look at [how to do that](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Targeting+Flash+Player+10).

Comment: Great thanks for your help. That was the missing link. It works.